# Running node.js server on Ubuntu using forever

Tags: node.js, npm, forever

I'm trying to use the 'forever' node.js package to run a node.js service on Ubuntu. Seems like it should be straightforward. However, when I run it, I receive the following output:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

I think this may be because the Ubuntu package manager names the node.js binary `nodejs`, rather than `node`, which is more standard. Is there a way to tell the forever package where to find node?

(I did try symlinking `/usr/bin/node` to `/usr/bin/nodejs`, but that produced even more errors and it feels like a hack anyway)

Comment: What is the command line that you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [installing the latest node from source](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation)?

```
git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
git checkout v0.8.22 #Try checking nodejs.org for what the stable version is
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=J6g53Hm0rq4#t=457s) isn't entirely clear, but the author implies that older versions of node in the Debian repository are behind the node/nodejs naming issue.

Alternatively, you could try finding the target of the /usr/bin/nodejs symlink using any of the methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130329/how-do-you-get-what-a-symbolic-link-points-to-without-grep) and create a /usr/bin/node symlink to that.

Good luck!